# python3 lxml How to get attribute value by name of attribute after XPath

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

When using the xpath method, how can I get the value of attribute ID (should be "DEF" in my sample below) which is a child of the result of my XPath?

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
f = StringIO('<root><row id="DEF">ABC</row></root>')
doc = etree.parse(f)
for c in doc.xpath("/root/row"):
       print (c.tag)
       #print (c.attribute('id').value)
       print (c.value)  #shows ABC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Retrieve attribute names and values with Python / lxml and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413678/retrieve-attribute-names-and-values-with-python-lxml-and-xpath).  It says that attrib will return a dictionary of attributes, then we can do the lookup in the dictionary:

```
   print (c.attrib['id'])
```

I'm using PyCharm, and it's not giving me all of the autocomplete choices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for c in doc.xpath("/root/row/@id"):
     print(c)
```

Your output should be `DEF`.

Comment: Sure that would work for this very specific case, but you changed the question.  I want to use the XPath I specified in the question, because my real world case has other attributes that I will be checking while looping.  I think my answer I found works for what I wanted.

Comment: @NealWalters Not sure I understand; maybe we're using different terminology: are you saying that each `<row>` has an attribute, that the attribute name (`id`, in your question) is unknown, and you want to select the attribute value (`DEF` in your question)? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm saying my real world example is more like this: <root><row id="DEF" attr2="HIJ" attr3="OPQ"  attr="XYZ">ABC</row></root> (of course multiple rows).  I need to retrieve each attribute by name. So plan to do the XPath on the element "row", then just print or do something with each attribute by name.

Comment: @NealWalters I see now. You can get all attribute values (`DEF`, `HIJ`, etc. in your example) by changing the expression to `/root//row/@*`. But to get all attribute names (`id`, `attr2`, etc., in your example), or both names and values, with just xpath you need xpath 2.0 and above, and lxml only supports 1.0. So I guess I can just delete the answer.

Comment: Your answer might help someone else down the road.  Thanks